# Please help! I don't know how to access the BLX I sent to MyEtherWallet - it says 0 balance but it shows on blockchain

Tags: transactions, wallets, tokens, recovery

I bought some BLX on EtherDelta, withdrew from contract to my EtherDelta wallet, then clicked "Transfer" and transferred all of my BLX to a MyEtherWallet address.

Later I got confirmation that it went through and I found the successful transaction on `etherscan.io`.

It was at the following:

```
 Block Height:
 4235569 (2265 block confirmations)

 TimeStamp:
 15 hrs 16 mins ago (Sep-03-2017 11:30:53 PM +UTC)
```

It gave the correct sending and receiving addresses, though the address it said received it was a Contract, not the MEW address I had specified.

It contains 0 Ether, Gas LImit 250000, Gas Used by Txn 37524, etc. etc.

I also found the whole transaction accurately recorded on ethplorer.io.

HOWEVER, MyEtherWallet shows 0 BLX tokens in my account when I look under Token Balances.

QUESTION: Are my BLX tokens still there? If so, where are they? How do I access them? What if I want to send them somewhere? MEW claims they don't exist, so how do I send them off of MEW? If they're not on MEW where are they and how do I access them?

Thanks in advance for your help. I am in full freak out mode right now!

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same problem and did some investigating. Currently the BLX ticker on myetherwallet is pointed towards the contract for Bullioncoin, and from what I can see, Bullioncoin is not using that ticker anymore, I cant find it being used anywhere.

If the transaction completed from ethdelta and was sent your correct wallet address, you should be fine, its an issue with the myetherwallet app, it has not been updated for BLX - Blockchain Index.

I am opening an issue on their github to see what the procedure is to fix this. I see that myetherwallet has the ability to watch a contract, but i havnt been able to get it to pick up BLX Blockchain Index from ICONOMI and am not even sure thats whats that feature is suppose to provide.

in short, your tokens should be fine. Once they update the app, your balances will display correctly.